# Unable to build docker from root

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am unable to build docker image from root, I have my Dockerfile in /, it gives error:

> root@onl-dev:/# docker build -t centoslibdemo . Error checking
>   context: 'no permission to read from
>   '/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush''.

Can someone suggest if there is any solution to this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Move your dockerfile out of your root directory.

There are a whole lot of reasons to do this, not the least of which is permissions issues. You should nearly never be using your root directory as your working directory.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  For another issue with it, running docker build / will create a tar file of your ENTIRE filesystem and ship it in memory to the docker daemon for the build process.

Comment: I tried building docker image keeping Dockerfile out of root directory which is /data/sept15/Dockerfile and used same with -f while building image : *docker build -f /data/sept15/Dockerfile -t centoslibdemo .* but still getting same permission issue.

Comment: Now the error is different (earlier it was permission issue)
`root@mymachine:/# docker build -f /data/sept15/Dockerfile -t mydemo .`
`Error checking context: 'readdirent: input/output error'.`

Comment: @Sweety your build context should not be root, which is what your last argument implies you are trying. You need to run it from that folder (or pass it your build context correctly).

Comment: @enderland, can you please let me know what do I need to do exactly here : " You need to run it from that folder (or pass it your build context correctly)", I am new to Docker and I dint understand the meaning of pass it your build context correctly, and from which folder I need to build docker image?

Comment: I have data and distros directories from which I am copying only required directories to my docker image through Dockerfile, so I have to build docker image from root only otherwise I won't be able to copy required directories from data and distros both in docker image. Can you please suggest me some way to do this?

Comment: If I try building docker file from distros:
`root@mymachine:/distros# docker build -f /data/sept15/Dockerfile -t centoslibdemo .
unable to prepare context: The Dockerfile (/data/sept15/Dockerfile) must be within the build context (.)`

If I try to build docker from data:
`root@mymachine:/distros# cd ../data/
root@mymachine:/data# docker build -f /data/sept15/Dockerfile -t centoslibdemo .`
It starts building, but it wont be able to copy directories from distros as it is in `../` path

Comment: Thanks, changed directory structure for docker image such that I don't have to use root (as we shouldn't use root for building docker image).

Comment: @Sweety glad to help!

Comment: @ElysianFields Can you please explain more about the reason that docker will fail with Dockerfile in root?